# xelatex biber on ubuntu cannot complile

Tags: biblatex, biber, linux

I try to run `xelatex` and `biber` as follow

```
xelatex myfile.tex
biber myfile.bcf
xelatex myfile.tex 
xelatex myfile.tex
```

However I cannot run `biber myfile.bcf`. It's probably because of my latest update on a ubuntu 16.04LTS machine. I get:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.6
INFO - Logfile is 'myfile.blg'
INFO - Reading 'myfile.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.1, expected version 3.2.
This means that your biber (2.6) and biblatex (3.4) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: update your `biblatex` package.

Comment: how to proceed ? sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade does not work

Comment: @gernot OK I have corrected this on the post.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, your version of Biber (2.6)  and that of `biblatex` (3.4) don't match, `biblatex` should be at 3.6 now. Did you install Biber via `apt-get` as well? If that is so and after an update of all other TeX-related packages you still get the version mismatch error (make sure to delete the temporary auxiliary files `.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl` before recompiling) you should complain with the Debian/Ubuntu package guys. They should ship matching package versions. You could use a vanilla TeX live instead of that from the repositories, then you can use `tlmgr` for updates.

Comment: You have installed `biber` from some non-standard repository. Ubuntu 16.04.01 comes with biber 2.4, 16.10 as well as the current developer release with 2.5, but you have 2.6. You have two options: downgrade biber, or install texlive 2016 independently of the ubuntu packages, see [TeX Live and Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html), section "Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian" (think Debian=Ubuntu as far as TeX Live is concerned).

Comment: @Swiss12000: You should install an own TeXLive version: https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu Then you can run the `tlmgr` yourself and have always the newest packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well finally I have decided to purge texlive

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive*
sudo su
rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2012 and rm -rf ~/.texlive2012
rm -rf /usr/local/share/texmf
rm -rf /var/lib/texmf
```

Then I decided to install a vanillia version of tex.

```
wget wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar -xzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz 
cd install-tl-20161022/
sudo ./install-tl
```

Wait a long time until the installation finishes. Then:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/environment
```

Adding `</usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:>` in the PATH

In my case `PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/tagada/Documents/eclipse"`

Saving the file.

Logout and login again for the changes to take effect.

Now start Terminal again and run:

```
which tex
```

This  show the following:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tex
```

Try to compile with `xelatex` and `biber`. It worked in my case.

I am not sure if it's the best solution. The solution of Herbert "You should install an own TeXLive version: [github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu](http://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) "  seems to be good as well. I haven't tried yet.

Comment: See also [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864) where one answer also links to the github repository you used.